# WooCommerce PayPal Pro jquery.payment checkout form improvements

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

What would be the correct way to hook into `WC_Gateway_PayPal_Pro` checkout credit card form to implement jquery.payment functionality on a custom theme?

env is up-to-date using:

- WooCommerce v3.0.7
- WooCommerce PayPal Pro (Classic and PayFlow Editions) Gateway v4.4.6

[jquery.payment](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment) ships with [WooCommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/assets/js/jquery-payment) and according to [this article](https://mikejolley.com/2013/12/14/using-new-credit-card-form-woocommerce-2-1/) (...probably out of date) enabling it is a matter of reverting to the default WC `credit_card_form`.

Now, I manage to display the form with working jquery.payment inputs using the following in 'functions.php':

```
function filter_woocommerce_payment_gateway_supports( $var, $feature, $instance ) {

    $feature = 'default_credit_card_form';

    return $feature; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateway_supports', 'filter_woocommerce_payment_gateway_supports', 10, 3 )
```

But this is far from working (never expected to be that easy), it just won't validate. Errors range from:

```
Payment error: There was a problem connecting to the payment gateway.
Payment error: Security header is not valid
Card expiration date is invalid
```

What I think I'm missing, as per the article, is "Modifying your form handler ... to ensure the gateway is looking for the correct post data", but how to? Can't find any relevant documentation on the following actions so looking for greatly appreciated pointers:

```
woocommerce_credit_card_form_args
woocommerce_credit_card_form_fields
woocommerce_credit_card_form_start
woocommerce_credit_card_form_end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to accomplish this is to enque WC's `credit-card-form.js` script:

```
/*
 * Enques credit-card-form.min.js to provide
 * better Credit Card form validation
 */
function filter_woocommerce_enqueue_styles( $return_false ) {
    if ( function_exists('is_checkout') ) {
        if ( is_checkout() ) {
            $WC_credit_card_form = plugins_url( 'woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/credit-card-form.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('wc-credit-card-form', $WC_credit_card_form, ['jquery', 'jquery-payment'], null, true);
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'filter_woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 10, 1 );
```